# Help needed to begin with a proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x),g (x) $ be two continuous and differentiable functions on [a,b] then prove that there exists a c such that $a <c <b $ and $\frac {f (b)-f (a)}{g (b)-g (a)}=\frac {f'(c)g^2 (c)}{g'(c)g (a)(g (b)} $. The part without $\frac {g^2 (c)}{g (a)g (b)} $ is a known Cauchy MVT which can be proved using $h (x)=f (x)+Ag (x) $ where $A\in R $ and using help of Rolles theorem.  But bringing that extra part in the proof is not easy.Any hints on how to start?Just the first step or an idea would do. Thanks!

Comment: What if $g(a)=0$?

Comment: I have written the exact question. Okay lets assume the required then how to continue?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the equality you're trying to prove can't possibly be true in general, because the right hand side is undefined in some cases, namely, for example, when $g(a)=0$.  To be very specific, consider $f(x)=g(x)=x$ on $[a,b]=[0,1]$.  The left hand side is simply $1$, but the right hand side is $(1\cdot c^2)/(1\cdot0\cdot1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions are needed. First that $g$ never vanishes in $[a, b] $ and second is that $g(a) \neq g(b) $. Another key assumption (which is coming from Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem) is that the derivatives of $f, g$ do not vanish at the same point in $(a, b) $. Ideally these assumptions should be mentioned as a part of the problem statement, but rarely do calculus textbooks put an effort in being mathematically correct so your situation is understandable.

---

Let $h(x) =1/g(x)$ then $h$ is continuous in $[a, b] $ and differentiable in $(a, b) $ with derivative $h'(x) =-g'(x) /(g(x)) ^{2}$. Clearly $h(a) \neq h(b) $ and further the derivatives of $f, h$ do not vanish at the same point in $(a, b) $. Then by Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem we have a $c\in(a, b) $ such that $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)} {h(b) - h(a)} =\frac{f'(c)} {h'(c)} $$ or $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)} {1/g(b) - 1/g(a)}=-\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)/(g(c))^{2}}$$ or $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)} {g(b) - g(a)} =\frac{f'(c) (g(c)) ^{2}}{g'(c)g(a)g(b)}$$

Comment: Thanks for understanding the situation and putting all the assumptions as separate paragraph.:)